# how to use external library within a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, import

plz help how to use external library(image slider library) inside a fragment,when extending to Fragment then error comes up in findviewbyid & when extending to FragmentActivity then FragmentManager does not support it.

Comment: elaborate and post your code

Answer (score 0):

did you add this?

```
dependencies {
        compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+"
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
        compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
        compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
}
```

to the gradle?

Also, check if Fragment is imported from support library.

Comment: so, try to change import of Fragment, it should help